# QtNetworkAccessManager crash

Tags: c++, qt

In relativly big QT project on android (arm), I am getting segmentation fault using **QNetworkAccessManager** (I have only one instance), when I call *get()* (it crashes every time).
Unfortunately, when I tried to create a small program for illustration which in *main()* creates *QNetworkAccessManager* object and called just *get()* it works as expected without crash, with response received. My application is crashing just when I call *get()*
to **https**, *get()* to **http** works like a charm. I am using **QT 5.4**. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl( QUrl("https://server"));
request.setRawHeader( "Accept", "application/something-v1+json" );

QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get( request );
```

Gdb backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x001abb1c in BN_copy ()
#1  0x001cffda in BN_MONT_CTX_copy ()
#2  0x001d072a in EC_GROUP_copy ()
#3  0x001d3dee in EC_KEY_copy ()
#4  0x001d3ec6 in EC_KEY_dup ()
#5  0x42141618 in ssl3_ctx_ctrl () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so.1.0.0
#6  0x413cc550 in ?? () from /usr/lib/sb/qt/lib/libQt5Network.so.5
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Comment: You might be getting the crash because the manager is not-existent. I'm not sure actually, but could not setting the parent cause any problem ?

Comment: Suggest adding the arm | android tag, might link to the wrong ssl lib.

Comment: Obviously the problem lays on establishing a secure connection to the server. Note the presence of `libssl.so` library in the stack trace and sending requests to `https` address.